# Search a value in all collections of MongoDB database using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Mongoose. I am struck to get data in every collection in Database.

I have some collections with a field **country**.

Lets say **company_Information** is collection having country as a field.

```
var companyInformation = new Schema({
  ....
  country:{type: String},
  ..
})

mongoose.model('company_Information',companyInformation);
```

similarly country field may present in some other collection.

Instead of searching a value of country in each collection using

```
company_Information.find({ 'country': 'India' })
someCollection.find({ 'country': 'India' })
someCollection2.find({ 'country': 'India' })
```

is there any way to search a record in every collection in database?

Working example would help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can use something like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const findAllCountries = (country_name)=>{
    let models = [];
    models.push(mongoose.models.someCollection1);
    ...
    models.push(mongoose.models.someCollectionN);

    return Promise.all(models.map(model=>model.find({'country': country_name})));
}
```

So you can use this function like this:

```
findAllCountries('USA').then(result=>{
   console.log(result);
}).catch(err=>{throw err;})
```